# How to Save string property with foreign key reference in database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I am working on an asp.net mvc project using entity framework and sql database.
On some action i want to save a notification message which contains reference of another model User

the two models are as follows

```
public class NotificationMessage
{      
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? FromUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FromUserId")]
    public virtual User FromUser { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

}


public class User 
{      
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }          
}
```

Now on some action i add a new notificationmessage to my database table and the message property is like

> "new notification from user"+FromUser.Name

Now if i change User's Name this message does not change as it is saved as static message in database.
**what i want is that this message will be saved in database in a way that if i change user's Name property this message will show the updated Name of User**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're persisting a bare `string` into the database, it will remain a `string` even if it's constructed using some data from related entity. The expression used to construct that string would not be re-evaluated each time you're accessing it (regardless of EF, that's natural `string` behavior).

You better change your `Message` to a computed property:

```
public string Message
{
    get { return "new notification from user" + FromUser.Name; }
}
```

Comment: but here i can not use computed property as my message will be of various format. here i have shown just one type. some type will not even have any user Name

Comment: Add that computation logic to the `Message` getter (instead of computing it upon insertion) to return the appropriate message. Also, consider changing it to `GetMessage()` method so it will be clearer that is indeed computed.

Comment: thank you. i guess i am clear now. when getting it for client side i will compute the logic